# Horizontal Scrolling for mobile and desktop - Is this a good idea?

Tags: usability, interaction-design

I'm re-doing my portfolio site with some updates.  As I was creating it I was thinking of various ways to present my work.  It's a mixture of iphone and desktop design work, sometimes both together. My original idea was to keep it a left and right rotating slide show.  But I came up with difficulties when trying to show a desktop design on mobile devices.  I came up with the idea of a sideways scrolling section.  It shrinks and grows depending on the size of the device.

My questions are, is it any good and if so do I need to give more of an indication that the user can scroll horizontally?  You can check out the prototype here:

[www.donalhanafin.com](http://www.donalhanafin.com/newsite/page1.html)

Answer (score 1):

It is completely subjective and you will find very different contrasting opinions on here. So here's mine:

In the right place they can be productive and add to the content. In particular it is a good way of prioritizing your content. For example, you've worked on 4 projects lets say and you want to show screen shots of all of them in multiple states. You may end up with something like this if you use only vertical scroll:

1:

XX

XX

XX

XX

2:

XX

XX

XX

XX

3:

XX

XX

XX

XX

4:

XX

XX

XX

XX

See where I am going with this? Its a long old scroll down.

So if you consider using horizontal scroll instead - much like your example, you can achieve more (with small x's representing photos just off the screen - scroll horizontally to see):

1:

XXXXxxxx

2:

XXXXxxxx

3:

XXXXxxxx

4:

XXXXxxxx

Obviously there are ways around a vertical scroll having this problem, make the photos smaller, make them click for more - but these are compromises you may not want to make.

This [previous UX question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/29180/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-mixing-horizontal-scrolling-with-vertical-scrollin) may also help. This debate, like infinite scroll, will remain forever contested IMHO.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  I think the point about making it clearer is important so I'll need to do something to make it obvious.  I think I'll try it and get some feedback.  I can revert to a carousel if it doesn't work but I think it's worth a go at least.  I'm only going to have one project per page.  I don't want to overload the page with imagery and have it take an age to load.  I have that problem with my current site.

Answer (score 0):

To make it clear that there is some kind of scrolling/paging functionality, it is helpful, to indicate via truncated content (which shows the direction where the full content is) or via visual representations (carousel, scrollbar).

Have a look at the attached screenshots of some examples:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use carousel.

PROS

- Works on all platforms
- Supports mobile gestures

CONS

- Not every user knows how to use carousel
- Auto-scrolling carousels are bad

For more detailed information check: http://uxmovement.com/navigation/why-users-arent-clicking-your-home-page-carousel/

Comment: Made me think of this: http://shouldiuseacarousel.com